# Designing box pattern using HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying for a pattern using HTML & CSS as shown in following Screenshot, I'm able to achieve this requirement upto [this](https://jsfiddle.net/e9f66dv9/) extent. Is there any way to adjust elements as shown in red lines in the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

```css
.bracketbox1,.bracketbox2,.bracketbox3,.bracketbox4,.bracketbox5,.bracketbox6{
                vertical-align:middle;
            }
            .bracketbox1 img{
                width:80px;
                height:80px;
            }
            .bracketbox2 img{
                width:85px;
                height:85px;
            }
            .bracketbox3 img{
                width:95px;
                height:95px;
            }
            .bracketbox4 img{
                width:105px;
                height:105px;
            }
            .bracketbox5 img{
                width:120px;
                height:120px;
            }
            .bracketbox5 img{
                width:140px;
                height:140px;
            }
            .bracketbox6 img{
                width:160px;
                height:160px;
            }
            .bordertop{
                border-top:1px solid #ccc;
            }
            .borderright{
                border-right:1px solid #ccc;
            }
            .borderleft{
                border-left:1px solid #ccc;
            }
            .borderbottom{
                border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
            }
            .margin5{
                margin:5px !important;
            }
            .margin10{
                margin:10px !important;
            }
            .margin15{
                margin:15px !important;
            }
            .margin20{
                margin:20px !important;
            }
            .tg  {border:0px solid #fff;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;width:100% !important;}
            .tg td{padding:5px;word-break:normal;}
            .tg th{padding:5px;word-break:normal;}
            .tg td{font-size:10px;}
            .tg hr{border-top: 1px solid #ccc;}
            div.bracket-empty-box { 
                width: 80px;
                height: 80px;
                border: 2px solid #888;
            }
            .mt-10 {
                margin-top: 20px;
            }
```

```html
 <div style="width: 320px;">
            <div style="display: block;">                
                <div class="clearfix"></div>   
                <table border="0" data-comboid="1" class="tg mt-10">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"><hr style="width:15px"></td>
                            <td rowspan="2" class="tg-yw4l">
                                <div class="bracketbox1">
                                    <div class="bracket-empty-box"></div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l bordertop borderright"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l borderbottom"></td>
                            <td rowspan="4" class="tg-yw4l">
                                <div class="bracketbox2">
                                    <div class="bracket-empty-box"></div>

                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td rowspan="2"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr> 
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"><hr style="width:15px"></td>
                            <td rowspan="2" class="tg-yw4l">
                                <div class="bracketbox1">
                                    <div class="bracket-empty-box"></div>

                                </div>
                            </td>                              
                            <td class="tg-yw4l borderbottom  borderright"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l bordertop"></td> 

                            <td class="tg-yw4l bordertop borderright"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l borderbottom"></td>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>                    
                </table>
                <table border="0" data-comboid="2" class="tg mt-10">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"><hr style="width:15px"></td>
                            <td rowspan="2" class="tg-yw4l">
                                <div class="bracketbox1">
                                    <div class="bracket-empty-box"></div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l bordertop borderright"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l borderbottom"></td>
                            <td rowspan="4" class="tg-yw4l">
                                <div class="bracketbox2">
                                    <div class="bracket-empty-box"></div>

                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td rowspan="2" class="tg-yw4l borderbottom borderright"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l bordertop"></td>
                        </tr> 
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"><hr style="width:15px"></td>
                            <td rowspan="2" class="tg-yw4l">
                                <div class="bracketbox1">
                                    <div class="bracket-empty-box"></div>

                                </div>
                            </td>                              
                            <td class="tg-yw4l borderbottom  borderright"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l bordertop"></td> 

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>                    
                </table>
                <table border="0" data-comboid="3" class="tg mt-10">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"><hr style="width:15px"></td>
                            <td rowspan="2" class="tg-yw4l">
                                <div class="bracketbox1">
                                    <div class="bracket-empty-box"></div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l bordertop borderright"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l borderbottom"></td>
                            <td rowspan="4" class="tg-yw4l">
                                <div class="bracketbox2">
                                    <div class="bracket-empty-box"></div>

                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td rowspan="2"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr> 
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"><hr style="width:15px"></td>
                            <td rowspan="2" class="tg-yw4l">
                                <div class="bracketbox1">
                                    <div class="bracket-empty-box"></div>

                                </div>
                            </td>                              
                            <td class="tg-yw4l borderbottom  borderright"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l bordertop"></td> 

                            <td class="tg-yw4l bordertop borderright"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l borderbottom"></td>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>                    
                </table>
                <table border="0" data-comboid="4" class="tg mt-10">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"><hr style="width:15px"></td>
                            <td rowspan="2" class="tg-yw4l">
                                <div class="bracketbox1">
                                    <div class="bracket-empty-box"></div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l bordertop borderright"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l borderbottom"></td>
                            <td rowspan="4" class="tg-yw4l">
                                <div class="bracketbox2">
                                    <div class="bracket-empty-box"></div>

                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td rowspan="2" class="tg-yw4l borderbottom borderright"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l bordertop"></td>
                        </tr> 
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"><hr style="width:15px"></td>
                            <td rowspan="2" class="tg-yw4l">
                                <div class="bracketbox1">
                                    <div class="bracket-empty-box"></div>

                                </div>
                            </td>                              
                            <td class="tg-yw4l borderbottom  borderright"></td>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l bordertop"></td> 

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>                    
                </table>
                <div class="margin5 clearfix"></div>               
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a quick solution, you could just add some `colspan`:

```css
.bracketbox1,
.bracketbox2,
.bracketbox3,
.bracketbox4,
.bracketbox5,
.bracketbox6 {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.bracketbox1 img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
.bracketbox2 img {
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
}
.bracketbox3 img {
  width: 95px;
  height: 95px;
}
.bracketbox4 img {
  width: 105px;
  height: 105px;
}
.bracketbox5 img {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
.bracketbox5 img {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
}
.bracketbox6 img {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
}
.bordertop {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.borderright {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.borderleft {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.borderbottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.margin5 {
  margin: 5px !important;
}
.margin10 {
  margin: 10px !important;
}
.margin15 {
  margin: 15px !important;
}
.margin20 {
  margin: 20px !important;
}
.tg {
  border: 0px solid #fff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
}
.tg td {
  padding: 5px;
  word-break: normal;
}
.tg th {
  padding: 5px;
  word-break: normal;
}
.tg td {
  font-size: 10px;
}
.tg hr {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
div.bracket-empty-box {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 2px solid #888;
}
.mt-10 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 320px;">
  <div style="display: block;">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <table border="0" data-comboid="1" class="tg mt-10">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="tg-yw4l">
            <hr style="width:15px">
          </td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="tg-yw4l">
            <div class="bracketbox1">
              <div class="bracket-empty-box"></div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="tg-yw4l bordertop borderright"></td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="tg-yw4l borderbottom"></td>
          <td rowspan="4" class="tg-yw4l">
            <div class="bracketbox2">
              <div class="bracket-empty-box"></div>

            </div>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="2"></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
          <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
          <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
          <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
          <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
          <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-yw4l">
            <hr style="width:15px">
          </td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="tg-yw4l">
            <div class="bracketbox1">
              <div class="bracket-empty-box"></div>

            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="tg-yw4l borderbottom  borderright"></td>
          <td class="tg-yw4l bordertop"></td>

          <td class="tg-yw4l bordertop borderright"></td>
          <td class="tg-yw4l borderbottom"></td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

But to give a space between `line3` and `line4` you should probably have to add more columns.

But I believe this is not a good practice, this is overly complicated for no reason, you could possible do this with fewer elements and a little more css, or with a js library and canvas in no time.

Comment: Thanks for your effort